# Как изменить дату не затрагивая время?

Tags: sql, oracle

Как можно изменить дату без времени, то есть чтобы время оставалось неизменным?

Формат `DATE`В БД: `01.06.2020 8:55:46`.

```
UPDATE t_pet t SET t.date_input='31.05.2020' WHERE t.id in (
111 ,
222 ,
333 )
```

Так получаю `31.05.2020 00:00:00`, а желаемый результат - `31.05.2020 8:55:46`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот так:

```
UPDATE t_pet t SET 
    t.date_input = date'2020-05-31' + (t.date_input - trunc (t.date_input))
WHERE t.id in (111, 222, 333)
```

---

Воспроизводимый пример ([на db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=61063e7f9b9d203cb9baf0215e0b2037)):

```
alter session set nls_date_format='dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss' 

select date'2020-05-31' + (dt - trunc (dt)) res from (
    select to_date ('01.06.2020 8:55:46') dt 
    from dual);

RES
-------------------
31.05.2020 08:55:46
```

Comment: Спасибо. Работает

Comment: Рад был помочь! Добавилк к вашему вопросу пояснение к желаемому результату, а то не очень понятно, что такое _дату без времени_. В истории правок есть кнопка откат, если что-то не так.

Answer (score 0):

Дата в БД представлена как число, где `1.0` соответствует одним целым суткам. Поэтому если необходимо изменить дату на известное количество дней с неизменным временем, то достаточно отнять/прибавить целое число дней.

```
select 
  dt - 1
from (select to_date ('01.06.2020 8:55:46') dt from dual);

RES
-------------------
31.05.2020 08:55:46
```

Иногда это удобно использовать, когда необходимо работать с часами и минутами. Например, прибавить 2 часа 30 минут (`1 / 24 * 2.5`)

```
select 
  dt + 1 / 24 * 2.5
from (select to_date ('01.06.2020 8:55:46') dt from dual);

RES
-------------------
01.06.2020 11:25:46
```